# Decoded string with html entities does not equal string literal

Tags: javascript, html, jestjs, escaping

I tried to implement the solution proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript/34064434#34064434) to decode a string with html entities, e.g. "foo&nbsp;bar" to "foo bar".

Visually, it seems to work. But my quick Jest test fails:

```
Expected: "foobar"
Received: "foobar"

  3 | describe('encryption/decodeHtml', () => {
  4 |   it.each([['foo&nbsp;bar', 'foo bar'], ['foo&shy;bar', 'foobar'], ['foo&amp;bar', 'foo&bar']])('should decode html entities', (val, expected) => {
> 5 |     expect(decodeHtml(val)).toEqual(expected);
    |                             ^
  6 |   })
  7 | });
  8 |
```

A quick `Object.is(decodeHtml('&nbsp;'), ' ')` also produces `false`.

Is there something to JS-Strings I'm not familiar with?

Comment: Where's `decodeHtml()`?

Comment: `decodeHtml('foo&nbsp;bar').split("").forEach(c => console.log(c, c.charCodeAt()));`

Comment: You're right, I forgot about the underlying char codes. I took value equality too literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas) in the comments, I forgot about the byte representation of the string.

Look at this example:

```
toBytes('foo bar') -> Uint8Array(7) [102, 111, 111, 32, 98, 97, 114]
toBytes(decodeHtml('foo&nbsp;bar')) -> Uint8Array(8) [102, 111, 111, 194, 160, 98, 97, 114]
```

In hindsight it pretty obvious because the breaking space and the non breaking space are (of course) different characters.